# Ethernet socket instead of the internet

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this code on both pcs to test a LAN connection, the server is connected to a modem and the client is wirelessly connected via a USB to an AP. Is it correct to use socket.AF_INET or should I use another socket

```
import socket

def Main():
   
    host = '192.168.100.114' #Server ip
    port = 4000

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    print("Server Started")
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("Message from: " + str(addr))
        print("From connected user: " + data)
        data = data.upper()
        print("Sending: " + data)
        s.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), addr)
    c.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Main()
```

---

```
import socket

def Main():

    host='192.168.100.144' #client ip
    port = 4005
    
    server = ('192.168.100.114', 4000)
    
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host,port))
    
    message = input("-> ")
    while message !='q':
        s.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), server)
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("Received from server: " + data)
        message = input("-> ")
    s.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Main()
```

I'm expecting to be able to send the text from the client via the USB connection to the AP and then back from the sever via the ethernet connect to the client. I'm not getting errors but the text is not received by the server since the AP is connected via usb connection to the client and via a modem to the server

Comment: (1) Format the code correctly. (2) It seems to be two code files. What is the second? The client code? (3) What happens when you run the files? If there is an error message, show it completely as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Read a tutorial about sockets, e. g. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html The server code misses calls of `listen` and `accept` while the client code shouldn't have a `bind` call.